# Regex for time interval

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to impose a regex pattern on a text input where an user can only insert a time between **9:00 and 17:00**.
I have tried the following which validates any time format but I am not sure how to get certain intervals restrictions.

This is what I tried:

```
([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

What would be the ideal regex pattern to verify that the time inserted in a text input matches the time between 9:00 and 17:00 ?

Comment: `/^((09|1[0-6]):[0-5][0-9]|17:00)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to define ORed ranges of numbers:

Regex: `^((0?9|1[0-6]):[0-5][0-9]|17:00)$`

Tests:

- `8:59` ==> false
- `9:00` ==> true
- `9:01` ==> true
- `08:59` ==> false
- `09:00` ==> true
- `09:01` ==> true
- `10:00` ==> true
- `10:01` ==> true
- `10:59` ==> true
- `10:60` ==> false
- `16:59` ==> true
- `17:00` ==> true
- `17:01` ==> false

Explanation of regex:

- `^...$` - anchor at beginning and end
- `(...|17:00)` - expect pattern A (explained below), or `17:00` (special case)
- `(...):[0-5][0-9]` - pattern A is pattern B, followed by `:`, `0-5`, followed by `0-9` for minutes `00` to `59`
- `(0?9|1[0-6])` - pattern B is ORed hour:
- `0?9` - optional 0, followed by `9` (for optional zero padding)
- `1[0-6]` - or a `1`, followed by `0-6` (for hour `10` to `16`